# how to parse xml-rpc formated xml with Microsoft.XMLDOM in delphi?

Tags: parsing, xml-rpc, delphi-10.2-tokyo

i´m starting an open source multi-platform project and need help parsing a xml-rpc xml file.

Since the name of the filed is a value, not a xml tag, I don´t know how to proceed to get the value from the name of the filed.

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are having trouble with. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a method to recursively navigate through all xml tags and return a TResult which is a type created to store all 3 fields of each tag.
(Name of the field, Data Type, Value).

My project is Open Source, i´ll post the link here if someone needs a tip on how to do it.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/subtitlegrabber/

Rad Studio 10.2.1 Tokyo.